# how to add files to zip using php, and these files should have a GET parameters

Tags: php, get, zip, php-ziparchive

I have a file `gen.php` this file should have some GET parameters like: `gen.php?oid=35852`
when open this link: `gen.php?oid=35852` will generate for download file called `35852.txt` using some php headers

now I'm trying to add these generated files to a zip archive using php `ZipArchive()` but it is not working

```
$zip = new ZipArchive(); // Load zip library 
$zip_name = time().".zip"; // Zip name

if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){ 
   // Opening zip file to load files
   $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
}

//this file will not added
$zip->addFile('/../../ser/gen.php?oid=35851');
//this file will not added
$zip->addFile('../ser/gen.php?oid=35852');
//this file will added, but as you see it will be the PHP file
$zip->addFile('../ser/gen.php');
//this file will added as a sample file
$zip->addFile('../samples2/2.png');

$zip->close();
```

is there any way to add the result files of `gen.php?oid=35851` that should be: `35851.txt` to the zip archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to download contents generated by `gen.php?oid=35852` into `35852.txt` file, and then compress the downloaded file in Zip, then you can use a code similar to the following.

```
$id = 35851;
$url = "http://yourdomain.com/gen.php?oid=$id";

$txt_name = "${id}.txt";
$zip_name = "${id}.zip";

$zip = new ZipArchive();

if ($zip->open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) !== true) {
   die("Failed to create zip archive $zip_name");
}

if (! $text = file_get_contents($url)) {
  die("Failed to download $url");
}

if (false === file_put_contents($txt_name, $text)) {
  die("Failed to write to $txt_name");
}

if (! $zip->addFile($txt_name)) {
  unlink($txt_name);
  die("Failed to add $txt_name to $zip_name");
}

$zip->close();

unlink($txt_name);
```

Comment: I got this error when I used the link: http://yourdomain.com/gen.php?oid=$id

Warning: file_get_contents(../gen.php?oid=35852): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\zip-gen.php on line 27
Failed to download file

and if I used it without ?oid=$id, it works properly

Comment: also this if used your script without any modifications:
Warning: file_get_contents(../gen.php?oid=35852): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\zip-ser2.php on line 17
Failed to download ../gen.php?oid=35852

as the previous it works properly if I removed ?oid=$id